# Unexpected error generated by the node js delete code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to delete a post in my node project, but it is throwing an error. Delete is working fine even then, but I am not able to figure out why and where this error is generated.

I have tried printing the steps in console. Please help me figure out what is the mistake!

router

```
.delete(cors.corsWithOptions, authenticate.verifyUser, (req, res, next)=>{
    Posts.findById(req.params.postId)
    .then(async (post) => {
        console.log('Post with id: '+req.params.postId+' found!');
        if(String(req.user._id) === String(post.posted_by)){
            if(post.image){
                fs.unlink('public/uploads/images/'+post.image  , async (err) => {
                    if (err) next(err);
                    console.log('file was deleted');
                });
            }
            post.remove()
            .then((resp) => {
                console.log('Post with id: '+req.params.postId+' removed!');
                // res.statusCode = 200;
                // res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html');
                res.redirect('/');
            })
            .catch((err) => next(err));
        }
        else{
            var err = new Error('You are not allowed to delete someone else\'s post!');
            err.status = 403;
            next(err);
        }
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .then((err) => next(err));
    
    // Posts.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.postId)
    // .then((resp) => {
    //     res.statusCode = 200;
    //     console.log('Post deleted', resp);
    //     res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html');
    //     // alert('The post has been deleted!');
    //     res.redirect('/');
    // }, (err) => next(err))
    // .catch((err) => next(err));
});
```

Error:

```
Post with id: 5f546a64dd65b83720448305 found!
ClientError [NotFoundError]: Not Found
    at E:\NodeJS Project\app.js:76:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\NodeJS Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (E:\NodeJS Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at E:\NodeJS Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (E:\NodeJS Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\NodeJS Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at E:\NodeJS Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
    at next (E:\NodeJS Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
    at next (E:\NodeJS Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:127:14)
    at E:\NodeJS Project\routes\postRouter.js:209:20
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
DELETE /post/5f546a64dd65b83720448305/edit?_method=DELETE 404 131.474 ms - 3752
file was deleted
Post with id: undefined removed!
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 82.387 ms - -
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:518:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (E:\NodeJS Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (E:\NodeJS Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:884:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (E:\NodeJS Project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:922:18)
    at E:\NodeJS Project\routes\postRouter.js:199:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this, it cleans up all the callback confusion

also note, you may be having issues with the filepath, you may need to add a `.` to `./public/...`

```js
// does not need to be in the route
const removeFile = (filepath) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      fs.unlink(filepath, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('file was deleted');
        resolve()
      });
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err)
    }
  })
}

app.delete(cors.corsWithOptions, authenticate.verifyUser, async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const post = await Posts.findById(req.params.postId)
    console.log(`Post with id: ${req.params.postId} found!`);

    if (String(req.user._id) !== String(post.posted_by)) {
      var err = new Error('You are not allowed to delete someone else\'s post!');
      err.status = 403;
      throw err;
    }

    if (post.image) await removeFile(`public/uploads/images/${post.image}`)
    await post.remove()

    console.log(`Post with id: ${req.params.postId} removed!`);
    res.redirect('/');
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
});
```